# Necessary component while delivering the Ant based Java Project

Tags: java, ant

I have a Java Project. Initially i started with .java and .class files. After that i deployed Ant to my project and now i have dist and docs folder in my project directory while also the build.xml .My question is while shipping this project which files should be given to the recepient so he can compile and run it and is there any dependencies that should be mentioned. Bytheway, the recepienet has asked me for the source code and the binaries. Also, do i have to worry about setting the ant classpath ?, Thanks

Comment: They need anything not generated. If you're not using a dependency management tool (like Ivy) then the polite thing to do would be to include the dependencies as well.

Comment: Or at least include a list of the dependencies (and where to get them if it's not obvious).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should deliver to your client, absolutely everything required to compile and run your program. Which would mean at a bare minimum the source, all dependent library files, and the build script, all nicely packaged up. Here's a basic layout you can use:

```
src         (all your source code here)
lib         (third party libraries here)
build.xml   (your build script)
```

Make sure you can build your project based off just the content in the laid out folders. Then clean up the folders, zip them into an archive and send the archive to your client.

Comment: how about ant. should i also include apache-ant-bin.zip in the lib ?

Comment: No, you typically don't include the build tool distribution. which of course creates the requirement that your client have Ant installed. But if they want the source they will need a build tool anyway so that should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ant to build your project and you have already created a `build.xml` file, then including this would help the person to build your project by specifying the dependencies etc.

The Ant site has example of a build.xml file. 
http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#example